# Pandoc markdown conversion with == highlighting

Tags: pandoc

I am using **Typora** Markdown text editor wherein highlighting text is done with `==[...]==` operation. This is also the case for many other Markdown editors such as **Obsidian, Quilt, iA Writer, etc**.

What is a way for *pandoc* to convert the `==` highlighting when converting to a pdf file ?

#### Sample.md

```
==Testing==
```

Then performing
`pandoc Sample.md -o test.pdf`
produces a pdf with "==Testing=="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: there isn't one, highlighting syntax is currently not supported by pandoc. For more details, refer to the related [discussion on the pandoc mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/C-OP94sfxAI/m/bDCQFS5tBAAJ).

The long answer is that you *could* write a [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters) or even a [custom Markdown parser](https://pandoc.org/custom-readers) to add support for various features, but that's non-trivial in this case.

Comment: Worth to mention, that @tarleb have already coded [such lua filter](https://gist.github.com/tarleb/a0646da1834318d4f71a780edaf9f870) and even more: current **pandoc** already supports that natively (via [**mark** extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-mark))